# .Net (WPF): ToggleButton linear gradient border

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, togglebutton

I have been working on a project recently in which i'm trying to create a toggle button with a linear gradient border colour, but i can't find a a solution.
I achieve that result on a normal Button but i'm struggling to find a way to do the same thing on a toggle button.

Toggle button on left and normal button on right (desiderate result)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNaPX.png

**Button code: (working)**

```html
 <Button Content="a" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="198,160,1017,85" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="65" Height="65" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Click="buttonPressed" Uid="a" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="3" Background="#FF4C8389">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7BC7CB"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
        </Button>
```

**Toggle Button:**

```html
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,160,0,0" Padding="5" Width="65" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Click="capslockPressed" Uid="capslock"  Height="65" FontFamily="Calibri" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"  />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C8389"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FF9CCFCF" BorderThickness="3">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9ec41d"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Thanks in advice for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the default template, you should specify which element should render your gradient using `TemplateBinding`.
You should use `TemplateBinding` for `BorderBrush` in template and specify your gradient in style setter.
This should do the trick:

```
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,160,0,0" Padding="5" Width="65" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Click="capslockPressed" Uid="capslock"  Height="65" FontFamily="Calibri" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"  />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C8389"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7BC7CB"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3">
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9ec41d"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

You can also specify the gradient for `ToggleButton` (not style) just like you did for regular button:

```
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,160,0,0" Padding="5" Width="65" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Click="capslockPressed" Uid="capslock"  Height="65" FontFamily="Calibri" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ToggleButton.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF7BC7CB"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ToggleButton.BorderBrush>
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"  />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C8389"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3">
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="↑"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9ec41d"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```